# rpm upgrade for particular architecture only

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

We build rpms of our product for 32bit and 64bit platforms. The name of product in rpm spec is defined something like

```
Name: foo
```

We pass `--target i586` to rpmbuild command line to build 32bit rpm and `--target x86_64` to build 64bit rpm.
We encode rpm arch in installation directory of the product so that we can have both 32bit and 64bit versions of the product installed at the same time.

We can install rpms just fine. E.g.: installing 32bit and 64bit variants of `foo` product, version v4.1:

```
rpm -i foo-4.1-i586.rpm
rpm -i foo-4.1-x86_64.rpm
```

But when we try to upgrade to version 4.2 32bit variant of installed product:

```
rpm -U foo-4.2-i586.rpm
```

rmp removes both 32bit and 64bit variants of installed products. This is undesired. So the question is: how should we tweak spec file or rpm command line so that we get upgrade only for chosen architecture?
The obvious solution would be to encode arch in package name in spec file, like this:

```
Name: foo-%{_arch}
```

But this doesn't look like common approach for package names. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

`--target` just set %_target, %_target_cpu, and %_target_os macros. It does not make sure your is build for target platform (unless your Makefile allows it). The correct way is to build it using mock:

```
mock -r epel-7-i386 foo.src.rpm
```

Then you will get r32-bit bit package and  you should be able to upgrade just one of them.

Comment: rpmbuild sets correct architecture in my binary rpms. So switching to other tool will not solve the issue.